# LINUX: How to calculate recursively the size of each sub directory up to root directory?

Tags: directory, size

[image]I have written this script Scrit in Linux.

I now need to know the  size for each sub directory with the condition `-atime +${DAYS}`  searching down from directory `$DIR`.
The result should be gathered in a text file `$FILENAME`.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Days ago to search
DAYS="1"
#Path to directory to be searched
DIR="/media/nss/MBVOL2/TEST1/"
#Result filename Solomon
FILENAME="/media/nss/MBVOL2/TEST1/solomon2.txt"
# Process of listing these files in a result text file 
find "${DIR}" -type f -atime +${DAYS} -print > $FILENAME
```

Comment: What does moving up the directory tree from `$DIR` to `/` have to do with the condition? Your question is quite unclear.

Comment: I need to to have list of files which have NOT been access for X days and calculate on a sub directory basis the size these files take.

Comment: I have rewritten your question because it was quite unclear (hence the answers including the use of `du`, please roll back the edit if you don't agree with my edits

Answer (score 5):

If you want the size of the subdirectories, use `du`. This will print the size of the subdirectories recursively (`-h` is for human readable sizes):

```
du -h /media/nss/MBVOL2/TEST1/
```

If you only want a summary and not each of the results, use `-s`:

```
du -sh /media/nss/MBVOL2/TEST1/
```

If you want the size of the directories regarding the `atime` condition of your script, you can use the following:

```
find -type d -atime +1 -exec du -sh {} \;
```

This will execute the command after `exec` (and before `\;`) and pass all the files found by the `find` command. However, bear in mind that you are actually accessing those files and directories, so the `atime` will be modified for them.

Comment: How do I capture the result in a another file?

Comment: Just redirect the output: find -type d -atime +1 -exec du -sh {} \; > /tmp/whatever

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe find through `du` in the final line to include the file size. Something like:

```
find "${DIR}" -type f -atime +${DAYS} -print0 | xargs -0 du -csh '{}' > $FILENAME
```

should get you close.

Comment: That doesn't give the size of the directories, just the size of individual files.

Comment: I have the result in a text file. But how do I obtain the size of each sub-directory up to root-directory? Thanks.

Comment: I need my above script to sum up for each sub directory: meaning I need to know the total size for sub directory A-CV  (line 20)then B-CV (line 37) then C-CV (line 59). Currently I do that with Excel but this not workable. Any idea?